# bash: using the conditional AND OR in if satement

Tags: bash, shell

I want to select files based on begin and end of file name. I wrote the code below but still having problems with my code, it is not printing anything.

Details:
My script below should loop over files places in the directory $path and check if the file name begin with (${t} **or** X${t} **and** ends with ".bz2") remov the file from repository.

```
t="T"
for f1 in $path/*; do
    if [[ ("$f1" == "${t}"* || "$f1" == "X${t}"*) && ("${f1: -4}" == ".bz2")]]; then 
       echo "IM here to remove files"
    fi
```

In my $path i have these files: **XT&20220202ffff.bz2**, **T&2022020mmmmmm.bz2**, **LMMMM.bz2**

Input are files in the $path output is removing the files.

Comment: Please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make your question more clear(not my downvote btw), cheers.

Comment: What is the exact value of the variable `path_` ? Is the `_` at the end a typo? `${f1:--4}` must have been `${f1: -4}`

Comment: yess @M.NejatAydin please have a look

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript` is a good place to start to get a trace of how actual execution is happening so you can ask a narrower question. Right now we need to know what your filenames are to know how this code is _supposed_ to work.

Comment: There must be a space after `:` if the index is negative: `${f1: -4}`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I correct it and rerun my script . Its is giving nothing.

Comment: Why not change your code to `for f1 in 'T/XT&20220202ffff.bz2' 'T/T&2022020mmmmmm.bz2' 'T/LMMMM.bz2'; do` so we don't need the glob to get the same results you do? -- mind, if your code isn't written to work right when `f1` contains `T/`, that could be your problem right there.

Comment: I cannot see a space after `:` in the code above

Comment: I gave samples of my data @CharlesDuffy there is lot of files. I will not do it manually

Comment: @M.NejatAydin And now?

Comment: We don't want you to do anything manually in your _real_ code, but we need a [mre] -- code we ran run our own machines to see your problem -- for this question to be on-topic. Our own machines don't have your files, so you can't use a glob that looks for filenames that only you have and meet [mre] requirements.

Comment: You should `cd "$path"` before the `for` loop and `for` loop should be `for f1 in *; do`

Comment: For me the condition is not working! When i removed then end partss condition i works perfectly.

Comment: If you use `set -x` (or `bash -x yourscript`) you should see _very clearly_ why the condition is not working. I told you to do this some time ago in the hopes you would follow the direction and see the problem yourself. `"T/X12345" == "X12345"*` will never be true because of the `T/`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, or one can just run `f1=${f1#$path/}` inside the loop while keeping it otherwise the way it is now.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes. Actually, the OP doesn't need a conditional operator. Using pattern matching, `for f1 in "$path"/{X,}"$t"*.bz2; do … done` should do the job.

Comment: You need a space before `]]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `for` loop nor the `[[...]]` conditional construct. All you need is pattern matching:

```
t="T"
echo rm "$path"/{X,}"$t"*.bz2
```

Drop the `echo` if the output looks ok.